# C# Unity how to select only one item in an array and deselect other items

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I have gameObject array that I'm looping through to animate the material with a delay for each gameObject. I am using a Coroutine in order to use WaitForSeconds and a for loop inside of it to add a delay for each object.

What ends up happening is all the objects in the array gets selected therefore the animation happens to all of them instead of just one object at a time

What I'm looking for, only the cube selected at the index to change color and to revert the color for the previous cubes.

How can I achieve that?

```
 public GameObject[] laneMat; 
 void Update()
 {
    StartCoroutine(matColor(laneMat, .3f));
 }

 IEnumerator matColor(GameObject[] gameObject, float delay)
 {
 time += Time.deltaTime;
  for (int i = 0; i < laneMat.Length; i++)
  {
     if (duration > time)
     {
         laneMat[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
         
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
     }
     else if (time > duration && time < duration + .3f)
        {
            Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            render.material.SetColor("_Color", originalColor);
            yield return null;
        }
    
 }
}
```

I tried Using List and making another loop inside the first loop to select the previes cubes and remove them with removeAt() but its a bit jittery and not the effect I'm looking for

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to add what this code currently does and how it is different from your expected output? It may help users try to understand your problem. I don't quite understand the issue here, but I'd be careful of having the coroutine the Update method: the coroutine will be triggered every frame. Have you considered putting the Coroutine in the Start method, and having the coroutine loop forever?

Comment: Thank you for comment, I have the Coroutine in Update because im doing the animation over certain amount of time and when that time is over, all gameObjects selected in the array go back revert to their original color.. i have much larger code that i didnt include i didnt want to cause more confusion but i guess i should have. I will edit the post

Comment: You should definitely not start a new Corotuine **every frame**! You will get hundreds concurrently running routines ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition to your loop here

```
    public GameObject[] laneMat; 
     void Update()
     {
        StartCoroutine(matColor(laneMat, .3f));
     }
    
     IEnumerator matColor(GameObject[] gameObject, float delay)
     {
     time += Time.deltaTime;
      for (int i = 0; i < laneMat.Length; i++)
      {
         if (duration > time)
         {
if(selected = true) { laneMat[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red); } else { laneMat[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.Color = defaultColor; }
             
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
         }
        
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the enumerator to be in the Start function, not the Update function. Calling StartCoroutine from Update means you start a new coroutine every frame that is independent of all the other coroutines you have already started.

If you move the call to the Start function, you can use delays wherever necessary to make the code wait. One way to revert the other game objects is with a second loop nested in the first loop. Since you'll have access to the index of the changed gameobject, you can simply avoid reverting that game objects material.

From there, it's just a matter of placing yield return statements wherever you want a delay.

```
 public GameObject[] laneMat; 
 void Start()
 {
    StartCoroutine(matColor(.3f));
 }

 IEnumerator matColor(float delay)
 {
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < laneMat.Length; i++)
        {
            laneMat[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
             
            //if you want a delay before reverting the other gameobject materials, it should go here
            
            for (int j = 0; j < laneMat.Length; i++) {
                if (j != i) { //if the index of the current gameObject is different from the one in the outer loop
                    laneMat[j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", originalColor);
                    
                    //if you want a delay between reverting each gameobject's material, it should go here
                }
            }       

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
        
        //if you want a delay before the process starts again, it should go here
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should be a good starting point.

Best of luck!